# MAMP + Laravel = Slow

Tags: php, laravel, delay, mamp

I have this weird thing going on with my setup right now that involves

**MAMP + Laravel**

Accessing Laravel and any of its routes, like the following gives me about 1 second delay.

```
http://127.0.0.1/test-controller 

Route::get('/test-controller', function () {
  dd("test-controller called, no DB access whatsoever");
});
```

Direct access to html, jpeg, php shown below have no delay.

```
/public/info.php
 <?php
    echo phpinfo();
 ?>

/public/info.html
<html>
<body>
info test from HTML
</body>
</html>
```

Using **php artisan serve** has no delay in all the above cases.

Any ideas what's wrong?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's normal that Laravel is slower compared to a simple HTML or php page on MAMP.  I don't really understand why you want to run Laravel on a MAMP stack, there are faster and better options such as valet. But thats my opinion .

Comment: It's my dev environment.  I don't understand why there's a 1 second delay to run using Laravel compared to ordinary PHP file.

Comment: You can't really compare loading a single PHP file to loading a framework. For Laravel, MAMP might not be the best option. There are multiple things that can slow down a application, such as debug mode, or other debug software on your dev environment.